# Does the external recruiter have to honor workplace communication policies when communicating with job candidates?

Tags: recruitment, ethics, company-policy, unprofessional-behavior

A an executive recruiter contacted me about a potential opportunity with a client of theirs.  After general 'initial' screening, I was asked to complete a lengthy document answering questions as 'prep' for interview with recruiter supervisor, then employer.

Technical hiccups delayed getting the completed doc to the recruiter.  I called and emailed several times.  Once when I was unable to return his call from the previous day, I emailed him instead.

The recruiter replied with a malicious email attacking my character and accused me of things that simply were not true.  It has all the credentials of a unprofessional, bullying workplace standards.

He represents the workplace communication policies of the company that he is an agent for, correct?

Should I alert the company?  How do I know he won't blast this email or slander my reputation?  It is ridiculous and there was no justification for his behavior or treatment of me.

Comment: You don't have to put up with someone being abusive of you. The next time you talk with him, explain that the kind of language and attitude he displayed are unacceptable. Also explain that if he continues, that further attempts for him to place you with a company will not continue. You can remind him that recruiters make their money by having people work. This attitude will not gather many willing to work for/with him.

Comment: Thank you Adam.  I have tried to reply by listing everything I did (email delivery dates, phone logs) to remind him that yes I actually did do what I said I was going to do.  But his reply did not acknowledge his abusive comments and in fact he made further unprofessional comments.  I don't want anything to do with him but don't want to risk his badmouthing me either.  Ugh!

Comment: Cut him off. There are other recruiters out there who will be more than happy to place you. And more than willing to be nice.

Comment: @auntkay Are you sure your recruiter is legitimate? I've had folk contact me about job offers that do not work for the company they claim to represent. If that doc you filled out requested your SSN you could be in trouble of possible identity theft.

Comment: cheawick - Yes.  I should have been more descriptive.  He is an external recruiter.  He doesn't have my ssn, but he does have my resume.

Comment: @auntkay In that case I would advise to contact the company the recruiter works for, make sure you specifically tell them the order of events that lead up to your email contacts with the recruiter, and also inform them that you can forward them your email correspondence with said recruiter. (I am assuming that you did not delete the email conversations.)

Pfft... I guess I should have posted this response in the answer section for you to determine if it meets your needs as an answer. I'm still getting used to this place too. =+P

Comment: @cheawick copy it into an answer.

Comment: @Styphon Done. I didn't think that would be allowed, thank you for the nudge.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an executive recruiter to me :-)  sounds like a backstreet flyby night using ten dollar words to make them selves look big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case I would advise to contact the company the recruiter works for, make sure you specifically tell them the order of events that lead up to your email contacts with the recruiter, and also inform them that you can forward them your email correspondence with said recruiter. (I am assuming that you did not delete the email conversations.)

Comment: cheawick - Thank you for your advice.  I'd also like to make sure this recruiter destroys my resume, I do not trust their ethics.

Comment: You are very welcome, sadly the hard part will be to ensure your resume will be duly erased. Also some sad news, but I expect to be banned from here very soon, if you recall I mentioned about how you word questions and answers, well I got myself into a pretty heated battle of words and don't expect to survive here long. This battle may well wipe me from the system here at StackExchange:http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/how-to-write-a-resume-for-a-career-change

Comment: @auntkay I wouldn't want them hanging on to my resume either if it were me - unfortunately I would say your chances of getting your resume gone from their systems is vanishingly unlikely, especially given their apparent level of professionalism. See [this answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/protecting-resume-against-recruiters-double-presentations-and-ms-word#answer-1143) in regards... (continued)

Comment: Although IANAL in some countries (for instance, here in Australia for me) there are laws that allow you to request they remove the information from their systems, they have the right to charge an "administrative fee" for this (I have seen it be roughly $30-40, which I think is extortion for the act of pressing delete). This also doesn't guarantee it's removal from the systems of anyone they have sent it to. Worse yet, if they have been just as unprofessional when speaking to companies on your behalf, you have no way of clearing the impression he has left on them in your name.